# What's it called when you like to do something because you're skilled at it

Tags: single-word-requests

What's it called when you like to do something because you're skilled at it?
My searches didn't yield much but I watched a presentation with this term in it and I can't remember what it was.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. Please take a moment to review the [single-word-requests tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) to see whether this question could be improved -- although it's reasonably clear, a sample sentence would probably help.

Comment: "Risk averse" works fairly well.

Comment: [Ludic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ludic) is often used for "doing a job because you enjoy it, rather than for the reward", but doesn't really cover the "skill" aspect of the question.

Comment: Single word requests should be accompanied by an example sentence that gives the context in which the word (or phrase) is used.

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to guess that the presentation you watched was on the concept of ***flow***.  The Wikipedia entry for [***flow***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)) introduces the idea this way:

> In positive psychology, flow, also known as the zone, is the mental
>   state of operation in which a person performing an activity is fully
>   immersed in a feeling of energized focus, full involvement, and
>   enjoyment in the process of the activity. In essence, flow is
>   characterized by complete absorption in what one does. Named by Mihály
>   Csíkszentmihályi, the concept has been widely referenced across a
>   variety of fields (and has an especially big recognition in
>   occupational therapy)...

*Flow* involves more than merely liking to do something because you're good at it, so if you are looking for a term that calls out and is restricted to this single element, *flow* isn't it.

A associated word, and a component of flow is the adjective, ***autotelic***.  The Oxford Dictionaries site offers this definition:

> (of an activity or a creative work) having an end or purpose in
>   itself.

Although not exactly what you asked, this word perhaps comes close to embodying the notion of work that is "its own reward".